# adding in the database with json type not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, laravel

i want to show in my project made with Laravel the avaibility of the doctor , with type json to show the avaibility in the morning and in the afternoon like this : 
Monday_morning:["8:30" ; "12:30"] 
So at first it was working , but after it just show me this one :
Monday_morning: "12:30" 
with the last time added

So this is my controller :

```
 'lun_mat1' => 'nullable',
            'mar_mat1' => 'nullable',
            'mar_ap1' => 'nullable',
            'mer_mat1' => 'nullable',
            'mer_ap1' => 'nullable',
            'jeu_mat1' => 'nullable',
            'jeu_ap1' => 'nullable',
            'ven_mat1' => 'nullable',
            'ven_ap1' => 'nullable',
            'sam_mat1' => 'nullable',
        $medecin= new doc() ;

        $medecin->Lun_mat_de=$request->input('lun_mat1');
        $medecin->Lun_apres_a=$request->input('lun_ap1');

        $medecin->Mar_mat_de=$request->input('mar_mat1');
        $medecin->Mar_apres_a=$request->input('mar_ap1');

        $medecin->Mer_mat_de=$request->input('mer_mat1');
        $medecin->Mer_apres_a=$request->input('mer_ap1');

        $medecin->Jeu_mat_de=$request->input('jeu_mat1');
        $medecin->Jeu_apres_a=$request->input('jeu_ap1');

        $medecin->Vend_mat_de=$request->input('ven_mat1');
        $medecin->Vend_apres_a=$request->input('ven_ap1');

        $medecin->Sam_mat_de=$request->input('sam_mat1');

        $medecin->save();
return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('medecin ajouter' ) ;
```

And this is the model  :

```
 protected  $table = 'doctors' ;
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
    protected $fillable = [
        'ID' ,
        'Photo' ,
        'demande',];

        protected $casts = [

        'Lun_mat_de' =>'array',
        'Lun_apres_a' =>'array',

        'Mar_mat_de' =>'array',
        'Mar_apres_a' => 'array', 

        'Mer_mat_de' =>'array',
        'Mer_apres_a' =>'array',

        'Jeu_mat_de' => 'array',
        'Jeu_apres_a' => 'array',

        'Vend_mat_de' => 'array' , 
        'Vend_apres_a' => 'array',

        'Sam_mat_de' => 'array',


        ];
```

and finaly this is the form :

```
 <p>Avaiability of doctor</p>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
  <label> Monday morning </label>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="lun_mat1" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="lun_mat1" />
  </div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  <label>Monday afternoon</label>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="lun_ap1" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="lun_ap1" />
  </div>
  </div> </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="rememberMe"> Fermer
</div>
</div>
 <hr color="#61BDE6">
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
  <label> Tuesday morning </label>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="mar_mat1" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="mar_mat1" />
  </div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  <label> Tuesday afternoon </label>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="mar_ap1" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="mar_ap1" />
  </div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="rememberMe"> Fermer
</div>
  </div>
  <hr color="#61BDE6">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
  <label> Wedensday Morning </label>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="mer_mat1" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="mer_mat1" />
  </div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  <label> Wedensday afternoon </label>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="mer_ap1" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="mer_ap1" />
  </div></div> </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="rememberMe"> Fermer
</div>
  </div>
  <hr color="#61BDE6">

  <div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
  <label> Thursday morning </label>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="jeu_mat1" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="jeu_mat1" />
  </div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  <label> Thursday afternoon</label>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="jeu_ap1" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="jeu_ap1" />
  </div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="rememberMe"> Fermer
</div>
  </div>
  <hr color="#61BDE6">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
  <label> friday morning </label>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="ven_mat1" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
  <input type="time" name="ven_mat1" />
  </div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  <label> Friday afternoon </label>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time" name="ven_ap1" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="ven_ap1" />
  </div></div>
  </div> 
  <div class="col-4">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="rememberMe"> Fermer
</div>
  </div>
  <hr color="#61BDE6">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-4">
  <label> Saturday morning </label>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time" name="sam_mat1" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  <input type="time"  name="sam_mat1" />
  </div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="rememberMe"> Fermer
</div>
  </div>
  </div> </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem you are facing is here:

```
<div class="col-4">
   <label> Monday morning </label>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
          <input type="time"  name="lun_mat1" /> /* input name is supposed to be like this lun_mat1[] */
      </div>
      <div class="col">
          <input type="time"  name="lun_mat1" /> /* input name is supposed to be like this lun_mat1[] */
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's wrong because you want to get lun_mat1 as array, but both of your above input name is the same, it should be changed to this for retrieving array value when posting to controller:

```
<div class="col-4">
   <label> Monday morning </label>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
          <input type="time"  name="lun_mat1[]" /> 
      </div>
      <div class="col">
          <input type="time"  name="lun_mat1[]" />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this, you can apply this rule for all of your input, if you want to retrieve array data when posting to controller, add `[]` after the input name